# Language C, algorithm runs well on LINUX and not on Windows 7?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So, guys, i was trying to implement a linked list algorithm in C, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista{
int info;
struct lista *next;
} *aplinked, strulinked;

aplinked insereNoFim(aplinked inicio, aplinked novo)
{
aplinked temp;
if (inicio == NULL)
    inicio = novo;
else{
    temp = inicio;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next = novo;
}
return inicio;

}

aplinked lenovo()
{
aplinked x;
x = (aplinked) malloc (sizeof(strulinked));
scanf ("%d", &x->info);
return x;
}

void exibe(aplinked inicio){
aplinked temp = inicio;
if (temp == NULL)
printf ("Não existe dados");
else
while (temp!=NULL){
printf ("\n info: %d \n", temp->info);
temp = temp->next;
}
}


aplinked remover(aplinked inicio, int x)
{
aplinked ant = NULL;
aplinked temp = inicio;
//procura o elemento na lista, guardando o anterior.
while (temp!=NULL && temp->info != x){
        ant = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
}
//verifica se achou
if (temp == NULL)
    return inicio; //no caso de não achar
if (ant == NULL)
    inicio = temp->next; //retirar o 1o elemento
else
    ant->next = temp->next;
free (temp);
return inicio;
}



int pesquisa (aplinked inicio, int x){
aplinked temp = inicio;
while (temp!=NULL){
    if (temp->info == x)
        return 1;
    temp = temp->next;
    }
return 0;
}

int main ()
{
int cont = 1;
aplinked inicio = NULL;
while (cont){
inicio = insereNoFim(inicio, lenovo());
scanf ("%d", &cont);
}
exibe(inicio);
printf ("Digite numero a ser pesquisado: \n");
scanf ("%d", &cont);
if (pesquisa (inicio, cont))
    printf ("achou o elemento buscado \n");
else
    printf ("não achou");

printf ("Digite elemento a ser removido: \n");
scanf ("%d", &cont);
inicio = remover (inicio, cont);
exibe (inicio);
}
```

Yep, the code is not in english, but you may have an idea of what it is about, so, a linked list, remove/insert/search/print functions, runs fine on linux, but it does not runs fine on windows!!

any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem in Windows? Can you please detail?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What did you see? What error symptoms do you get?

Comment: Define: what does `not run fine in Windows` mean.

Comment: what's the compiler used to compile the windows version?

Comment: Run it under `valgrind`, and see if things are as fine as you assume, they were ...

Comment: Here is good stuff to start with **gdb**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-zAgbDq5pk

Comment: thanks guys, i did fixed the problem, it was inside the function "lenovo()" i did not fill the x->next with NULL...! thanks anyway, guys!

Comment: `if (inicio == NULL)
    inicio = novo;` //<- not change pointer

Answer (score 2):

I highly recomend you learn how to use a debugger. This is your problem:

```
aplinked temp;
if (inicio == NULL)
    inicio = novo;
else{
    temp = inicio;
    while (temp->next != NULL)  //  you never set this to NULL
        temp=temp->next;
```

Because you never explicitly set `temp->next` to `NULL` it could have anything in it. Apparently on Linux it's NULL (you got lucky) and on Windows it's just junk.. `junk != NULL` so it tries to set and dereference it and then you crash.

You should be filling in *all* elements of the struct in you `lenovo()` function, not just `info`

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate a new node, you don't initialize its `next` pointer. This means it will point to a seemingly random location, and when you try to find the end of the list it will continue looping over the actual end.